# How is the best way to perform this search in my mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables and its respectives structure:

```
users: id(1),name
colors: id(2),name,tags
hobbies: id(3),name,tags
userSettings: id,int(1) userid,int(2) color,int(3) hobbie
```

Tables values:

```
users: {1,john},{2,ana}

colors: {1,blue,blue azul celeste },{2,red,red vermelho rosso}

hobbies: {1,sing,cantare cantar sing},{2,run,running correr runner}

userSettings: {1,1,1,2},{2,2,2,1}
```

So... what I need is to find which users has the color or hobbie searched by the user. For example: if I search by `"blue"` or `"runner"` I have to find user `1 - John`.

If I search by `"rosso"` or `"sing"` I have to find user `2 - Ana`. I know how to do this with 3 queries but I know that exists a method to improve this to just one query that would be fast since the fields are indexed.

Does any one can help?

Comment: It is not clear if your data is JSON or normal MySQL table rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a fulltext index to the tables you want to search, then join the tables in the query.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/peZLQ6PVLMRCytcP9EUp3f/12

**Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('john'), ('ana');

CREATE TABLE colors (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(255),
tags varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FULLTEXT (tags)
);
INSERT INTO colors (name, tags)
VALUES
('blue','blue azul celeste'), 
('red','red vermelho rosso');

CREATE TABLE hobbies (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(255),
tags varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FULLTEXT (tags)
);
INSERT INTO hobbies (name, tags)
VALUES
('sing','cantare cantar sing'), 
('run','running correr runner');

CREATE TABLE userSettings (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
userid int,
color int,
hobbie int,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO userSettings (userid, color, hobbie)
VALUES
(1,1,2), 
(2,2,1);
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users 
LEFT JOIN userSettings ON userSettings.userid = users.id 
LEFT JOIN colors ON colors.id = userSettings.color 
LEFT JOIN hobbies ON hobbies.id = userSettings.hobbie 
WHERE 
MATCH(colors.tags) AGAINST ('runner' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR MATCH(hobbies.tags) AGAINST ('runner' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
;
```

---

Or you could create a `view` table. EG:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8kojtBefpySA4ckDqM747H/2

**Schema**

```
//As above +

CREATE VIEW searchview AS (SELECT userid, users.name as name, concat_ws(' ',colors.tags,hobbies.tags) as tags FROM users 
LEFT JOIN userSettings ON userSettings.userid = users.id 
LEFT JOIN colors ON colors.id = userSettings.color 
LEFT JOIN hobbies ON hobbies.id = userSettings.hobbie);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM searchview
WHERE tags REGEXP '[[:<:]]runner[[:>:]]';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really going to depend on how you're implementing your search (I assume you're using PHP?)

In general something like this could work, if you replace the word by the variable in your search form:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table users (id int, name varchar(10));
create table colors (id int, name varchar(10), tags varchar(50));
create table hobbies (id int, name varchar(10), tags varchar(50));
create table userSettings (id int, user_id int, color_id int, hobbie_id int);

insert into users values (1, 'John');
insert into users values (2, 'Ana');

insert into colors values (1,'blue','blue azul celeste');
insert into colors values (2,'red','red vermelho rosso');

insert into hobbies values (1,'sing','cantare cantar sing');
insert into hobbies values (2,'run','running correr runner');

insert into userSettings values (1,1,1,2);
insert into userSettings values (2,2,2,1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select u.* from users u, colors c, hobbies h, userSettings us 
where 
us.user_id = u.id and
us.color_id = c.id and
us.hobbie_id = h.id and
(c.tags like '%blue%' or 
 h.tags like '%blue%' or 
c.name like '%blue%' or 
 h.name like '%blue%'
);

| id  | name |
| --- | ---- |
| 1   | John |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The following query should get the job done as expected. The logic is to `LEFT JOIN` the `users` table with the `colors` and `hobbies` table, using `userSettings` as a bridge. The search parameter is checked in the join conditions. Then, the `WHERE` clause ensures that at least one hobby or color matches the search parameters :

```
SELECT u.*
FROM 
    users u
    LEFT JOIN userSettings us ON us.user_id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN colors c 
        ON c.id = us.color_id  
        AND ( c.name = @search OR c.tags LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%') )
    LEFT JOIN hobbies  h 
        ON h.id = us.hobbie_id 
        AND (h.name = @search OR h.tags LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%') )
WHERE
    c.id IS NOT NULL OR h.id IS NOT NULL
```

You can see it action with your sample data in this **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gG2vQT7PTyUWcfbPUVw48C/2)**. For example, when searching for `'sing'`, this returns :

```
| id  | name |
| --- | ---- |
| 2   | Ana  |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id || ' - ' || u.name as USER
FROM userSettings us
JOIN users u
    ON u.id = us.userid
JOIN colors c
    ON c.id = us.color
JOIN hobbies h
    ON h.id = us.hobbie
WHERE 
    c.name LIKE '%blue%'
    OR c.tags LIKE '%blue%'
    OR h.name LIKE '%runner%'
    OR h.tags LIKE '%runner%';
```

**Input:**
Search for blue or runner

**Output:**

```
USER
1 - John
```